# Git Merge: qué pasa si fusiono dos ramas que no son master

Tags: git

Digamos que tengo el siguiente escenario: el master, la rama1(de un compañero) y la rama2(actual mia sobre la que estoy trabajando). Mi pregunta es qué pasa si hago un merge de la rama1 sobre mi rama2. La rama1 se borra? No quiero que mi compañero pierda o se le modifique su rama1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las ramas no se borran a menos que lo hagas explícitamente, lo que ocurre es que todos los cambios de la **rama1** hechos *después* de que la **rama2** se crease se añadirán a la **rama2**. Pero la **rama1** no se verá afectada de ningún modo.

De hecho la rama **master** no tiene nada de especial, aparte de llamarse master, un `merge` actúa siempre igual, sean cual sean las ramas.

Puedes encontrar más información [aquí](https://git-scm.com/book/es/v2/Ramificaciones-en-Git-Procedimientos-b%C3%A1sicos-para-ramificar-y-fusionar), que es parte del libro online gratuito sobre git que puedes encontrar [aquí](https://git-scm.com/book/es/v2)

Answer (score 0):

Al realizar un merge de una **rama** a otra la anterior no es borrada, pero puede que tengas algo llamado **conflictos** en el merge, para esto te recomiendo instalar una herramienta llamada **MELD**, y realizar la configuración de este en git con el siguiente comando

`git config --global merge.tool meld
 git config --global mergetool.meld.path /c/Program files (x86)/Meld/meld/meldc.exe`

una ves instalada este puedes usarlo cuando se generen conflictos usando el comando

`git mergetool`

Comment: Esta respuesta está basada en opiniones: recomendar una herramienta u otra no es algo que se haga en SO.es. Y se sale de la temática de la pregunta